# Strange Behaviour of Resources and x:Bind

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the following code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BindingTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BindingTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="{x:Bind myColor}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPressed" Color="Red" />

        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button>Click me!</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>

// MainPage.xaml.cs
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace BindingTest {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {

        private string myColor = "Red";

        public MainPage() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the program, I get a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

When I comment out one of the lines in the `Resources`-block (regardless of which), the program starts without exception. And when I replace the `{x:Bind myColor}` with a hardcoded value, for example `Green`, the program works too, but as said, the program works also, when I have only the line with `{x:Bind myColor}` (and the other one commented out).

What can cause this strange behaviour and how can I fix it?

Comment: But strange is, that `<Grid.Resources><SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="{x:Bind myColor}" />` (without the hardcoded value) works. Do you have a idea why?

Comment: *without the hardcoded value* what's that mean?

Comment: In the example in my question, I have under the line with the binding a second line, where I set `ButtonForegroundPressed` to `"Red"`. When I remove that line, the `x:Bind` seems to work.

Comment: Interesting. So you see no possibility to set both ButtonForegroundPointerOver and ButtonForegroundPressed with a binding?

Comment: Yep, we don't suggest set binding in `Resources`. if you want to bind a dynamic SolidColorBrush , you could try to set it in your viewmodel.

Comment: Okay, then I will have to do that. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any updates for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In `Page`/`Grid`'s resource, you can't use that way, they can be static resources, so you can only use `{StaticResource xxx}`. So you can define your color in `App.xaml` file like below as static resources.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myColor" Color="Red"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can use you defined color in this way.

```
<Button Background="{StaticResource myColor}"/>
```

Comment: But then I don't understand, why this code: `<Grid.Resources><SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="{x:Bind myColor}" /></Grid.Resources>` (without the second `SolidColorBrush` with the hardcoded value) works?